# Log in with psql

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am trying to run postgres from terminal. What am I missing?

```
$psql
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
LANGUAGE = (unset),
LC_ALL = (unset),
LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
LANG = "en_GB.UTF-8"
are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're on a system with [`pg_wrapper`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/pg_wrapper.1.html) like Ubuntu or Debian, and your locale settings are messed up. This isn't to do with PostgreSQL, it's a system configuration problem. Perl is just complaining about it.

Run `perl` without arguments and you'll see the same complaint.

Assuming you're on Ubuntu since you didn't say otherwise, see:

- [Locale - Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale)
- [How to select and generate locales on Ubuntu - UbuntuGeek](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-select-and-generate-locales-on-ubuntu.html)

Comment: Yes I am on ubuntu and will look into your links

Comment: @user874774 You might just need to regenerate the locale data.